# Define characteristics (wave lengths, etc) of bands created by split order in Orfeo Toolbox

Tags: qgis, orfeo-toolbox, orthophoto, splitting

I have an orthophoto layer (exported from photoscan, drone images) that consist of four bands.

I extracted bands using "split image" order, but I can't understand which of them are NIR, green, red and red edge. How I should understand the output of the split image tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The split image application split image's bands in the order in which it is encoded in the image file.

To know which bands corresponds to which wave lengths you need to refer to the metadata associated to the image. The order of bands and their corresponding wave lengths may differ depending of the convention use by the data provider.

Comment: In metadata I see the characteristic of the band but I don't know which of them is NIR or red etc, in meta data it isn't mentioned.

Comment: NIR corresponds generally to wavelenghts between 0.75–1.4 µm, but it can defer depending on the sensor specification. You should probably ask the question to the data provider

Comment: thanks dear Manuel. this data gathered from eBee SQ and a company that uploaded this data in https://www.dropbox.com/sh/sjkcl2h7yk5hf02/AACSfhxXjdlUyqDaJ5y-PcaGa?dl=0